# unable to clear login information in Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I recently logged into Microsoft WAAD account using an webview, on further opening of the app again for testing i do not see the login page of Microsoft however i would be taken to next page after login directly.

i tried these things:

```
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearFormData();
webView.clearHistory();
webView.clearSslPreferences();
getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("webview.db");
getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");

getBaseContext().deleteDatabase("webview.db");
getBaseContext().deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
```

but my issue is not yet solved. anything else to be done ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything okay, but you need to delete the cookies as well

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
     cookieManager.removeAllCookies(new ValueCallback<Boolean>() {
     @Override
         public void onReceiveValue(Boolean aBoolean) {

         }
     });
}
else{
     cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
}
```

This is how you would disable them alltogether

```
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getActivity());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        cookieManager.removeAllCookies(new ValueCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(Boolean aBoolean) {

            }
        });
    }
    else{
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    }
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(false);

    WebView webview = new WebView(getActivity());
    WebSettings ws = webview.getSettings();
    ws.setSaveFormData(false);
    ws.setSavePassword(false); // Not needed for API level 18 or greater (deprecated)
```

Comment: ok. So i see that cookies manager is not tied to webview, so i assume webviews are like browser tab but all storing cookies with help of one manager per application...

Comment: i had gone through the document but i had not understood the point that webview and cookie manager will not be tied up.